# how to add two methods together in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have this following method:

```
document.formcalc.txtres.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(num2);
```

But I also want to add the round method: `Math.round(num2);`

Can someone explain me how to add this two methods together?

Answer (score 1):

Just provide num 2 to `Math.round` and put it whole inside the `format()`

```
document.formcalc.txtres.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(Math.round(num2));
```

Comment: If it helped you upvote and mark it as correct so that it can help others too

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for; if it's not, I added a second statement that you can try aswell.

```
document.formcalc.txtres.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(Math.round(num2));
```

And the other solution:

```
document.formcalc.txtres.value = Math.round(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-CH', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CHF' }).format(num2));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the newbies out there, The answer by ellipsis worked great but what you're looking at can be found here [http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat.html#:~:text=Intl.NumberFormat%201%20Summary.%20The%20Intl.NumberFormat%20object%20is%20a,A%20reference%20to%20Intl.NumberFormat.%20...%205%20Examples.%20](http://www-lia.deis.unibo.it/materiale/JS/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat.html#:%7E:text=Intl.NumberFormat%201%20Summary.%20The%20Intl.NumberFormat%20object%20is%20a,A%20reference%20to%20Intl.NumberFormat.%20...%205%20Examples.%20)

In my case, I needed to take away the locale, 'de-CH'. Currency worked well for me as the style and I changed the currency to USD.

```
var num2=(12/5);
document.formcalc.txtres.value= new Intl.NumberFormat({ style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(Math.round(num2));
```